# is it possible to use pm2 to watch and graceful reload?

Tags: pm2

I have pm2 running my node app, and was wondering if I can make sure it is reloading with zero downtime on the watch, rather than just restarting. Here is a sample json file that is setup how I am using pm2.

```
 {
   "name"             : "server",
   "cwd"              : "/home/user/website",
   "script"           : "server/server.js",
   "instances"        : 2,
   "max_restarts"     : 0,
   "watch"            : true,
   "ignore_watch"     : ["some/files"],
   "env_staging": {
     "NODE_ENV": "staging"
   },
   "env_production": {
     "NODE_ENV": "production"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nope, got the same problem, according to the documentation and source code, this is not possible

Comment: Yeah, from what I am seeing the best solution is to remove the watch entirely, and either use a script, or pay for keymetrics and use their GUI to do a graceful reload on multiple servers with ease.